# What is the space $T_Y^*X$?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Help with notation! I'm a physicist, but I've come across the following notation, $T_Y^* X$ where $Y$ is a complex analytic submanifold of $X$.  A phrase I've heard used is "conormal bundle" but is that the right notation for it?  Can someone provide me with a definition when $X=C^n$?

Comment: It's easy to give *an* answer: we have an inclusion $TY \subset TX$. The quotient is the normal bundle, and the dual of that is the conormal. [I'm used to these things in the algebraic category, so hopefully I'm not messing this up.]

Comment: $T^*$ looks like the cotangent bundle, in which case this would just be the cotangent bundle of $X$, restricted to $Y$.